# TextView above SeekBar Thumb is shifted

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I'm making a custom SeekBar that has a TextView above the thumb as follows:

[image]

The code im using is (the -30 is the width of the textview to center it):

```
SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        int val = (progress * (seekBar.getWidth() - 2 * seekBar.getThumbOffset())) / seekBar.getMax();
        Tv_SbDistanceText.setText(progress + " Km");
        Tv_SbDistanceText.setX(seekBar.getX() + val + seekBar.getThumbOffset() / 2 - 30);

        Show_Map(dpWidth, dpHeight, Lat, Lon, progress*1000);

    }
```

Thing is, that when I move the thumb the textview is being shifted more and more:

[image]

(It is not because of the -30, I tested with and without it)

Is there a way I can make sure it will always stay right above the center of the thumb?

The xml is:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sb_radius"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progress="10"
    android:min="1"
    android:max="300"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:thumb="@drawable/sb_thumb"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/sb_style"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sb_text"
    android:splitTrack="false">
</SeekBar>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its in Kotlin you can convert it easily.
Accept the answer, if it helped you.

```
sbTest.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
    {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) {

        val value = seekBar?.progress
        tvPos.text = "$value Km"
        if(value!=0) {

            val cur = seekBar!!.width/seekBar.max

            tvPos.x = (cur * value!!).toFloat() +10
        }
        tvPos.y = seekBar?.pivotY!! + 10
        Log.d("Pos", tvPos.x.toString() + ": " +seekBar!!.width+":" +seekBar.x)
    }
```

[image]
        Here's java, Get the max length of seekbar and divide the width of seekbar with it and multiply progress to get exact value of x-axis, adding different values to x-axis so text can stay in middle of point.
Subtracting -50 from y-axis, so it can stay on top of point.

> You can adjust if/else according to your need.

```
              float value = seekBar.getProgress();

            float currentPosition =  (float)seekBar.getWidth() / seekBar.getMax();

            currentPosition = currentPosition * value;

            Tv_SbDistanceText.setText(value + " Km");

            if(value<100)
                Tv_SbDistanceText.setX(currentPosition +50);
            else
                Tv_SbDistanceText.setX(currentPosition+10);

            Tv_SbDistanceText.setY(seekBar.getY() - 50);
```

[image]

Comment: Either I translated it wrong to Java or it is still biased:  Tv_SbDistanceText.setX(seekBar.getX() +  (seekBar.getWidth()/seekBar.getMax())*progress + 10);

Comment: Its not working mate. I dont know if its either because the seekbar is starting not from the beginning of the screen and seekbar.getX() is required or if its because the end of the seekbar is not at the end of parent aswell.

Comment: kindly share your xml too.

Comment: you may check now, i have adjusted it according to your xml.

Comment: Its weird that there is a need to use condition for such thing but it works in this case. thank you.

Comment: the TextView moves when progress changes, can you suggest how to set TextView below thumb when seekbar progress set to 80 (Radnumb Number) in OnCreate()

Comment: @Sniffer replace "-" with "+" in setY at last line and if you want to set at specific value then just add a if check for it.